# Accessing res variable from multer disk storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

I'm hung up on this issue using the multer library on my Node server.  I'm trying to upload a file or files and then make a call to the database for each file and then send back success or failure to the client.

So my Node server route for uploading the file(s) looks like this:

```js
app.post('/uploadFiles', (req, res) => {
    upload(req, res, async function (err) {
    ...
```

Then that upload function is simply this:

```js
const upload = multer({ storage: multerStorage }).array('file');
```

And then the multerStorage function that handles the destination and filename for multer:

```js
const multerStorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, process.env.LABELS_LOCATION);
    },
    filename: async function (req, file, cb) {
        // save file info to DB
        const itemID = file.originalname.slice(0, -4);
        const addLabelResult = addLabelToDB(itemID, 0);
        // console.log({ addLabelResult });
        // console.log({ itemID });
        // console.log({ file });
        cb(null, file.originalname);
    },
});
```

And finally the `addLabelToDB` function:

```js
    const addLabelToDB = (itemID, enterType) => {
        const sp = 'insertLabelHistory';
        const inputs = [
            { name: 'itemID', type: sql.NVarChar, value: itemID },
            { name: 'enterType', type: sql.Bit, value: enterType },
        ];
        return executeSP(res, sp, inputs);
    };
```

So the issue is that, if you look at the `addLabelToDB` function, you can see the call to `executeSP` takes in a `res`.  And I want that `res` from the original `/uploadFiles` route.  But I don't know how to access it from here.  And if there a better completely different way to do this, I am all ears.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you already solved your issue but for future people with the same issue here it goes:

Remember that you can access res from req by `req.res`

In your case you can just pass res to addLabelToDB, here's how:

```
const multerStorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, process.env.LABELS_LOCATION);
    },
    filename: async function (req, file, cb) {
        // save file info to DB
        const itemID = file.originalname.slice(0, -4);
        const addLabelResult = addLabelToDB(req.res, itemID, 0);
        cb(null, file.originalname);
    },
});
```

And then on your addLabelToDB:

```
    const addLabelToDB = (res, itemID, enterType) => {
        const sp = 'insertLabelHistory';
        const inputs = [
            { name: 'itemID', type: sql.NVarChar, value: itemID },
            { name: 'enterType', type: sql.Bit, value: enterType },
         ];
        return executeSP(res, sp, inputs);
    };
```